# UICollectionView Bounds Width is always 600

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uiedgeinsets

I have a custom `UIView` say `CustomView` which has a `UICollectionView` as its SubView. I have added this customView inside a UITableView Prototype Cell and pined all four (top, bottom, left, right) edges to the standard distance with `TableViewCell`.`contentView`.

Now i want to set the `UICollectionView` section insect. In this method `- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section` when i get `UICollectionView.bounds.width`, i always get `600` no matter if i am running it on 4s, 5s, 6 or 6 plus or iPad. This is very annoying and i can't set the proper `insect` for the `UICollectionView` section insect. Any help will be great. thanks

Here is my code.

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {

  NSInteger number = [self collectionView:collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section];
  NSIndexPath *firstIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:section];
  CGSize firstSize = [self collectionView:collectionView layout:collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:firstIndexPath];
  NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:number - 1 inSection:section];
  CGSize lastSize = [self collectionView:collectionView layout:collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath];
  UIEdgeInsets  insect =  UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, (collectionView.bounds.size.width - firstSize.width) / 2,
                                           0, (collectionView.bounds.size.width - lastSize.width) / 2);

  return insect;

}
```

here is my initlize of my CustomView which has collectionView as a subView

```
- (void) initilize {
  UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc ] init];
  flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
  self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds collectionViewLayout: flowLayout];
  self.collectionView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
  [self.collectionView registerClass:[PickerCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PickerCollectionViewCell"];
  self.collectionView.delegate = self;
  self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
  self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  self.collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
  self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
  [self addSubview:self.collectionView ];
  self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Attached are also two images for my story board.

[image]

[image]

In the second picture pickerView is my CustomView which contains `UICollectionView`.

Any help will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Width equals 600 because you take it before UIView updates constraint for current screen. You can check UICollectionView frame in `- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews` method and you will receive actual value.
Here is two options:
1) You can make insects calculation independent from UICollectionView frame
or

2) You can re-calculate collection view layout after when `viewDidLayoutSubviews` fires and redraw UICollectionView
*(I would rather the first one)*