# How to show a collectionView like facebook upload image using swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift4, uicollectionviewflowlayout

[image][image]

Hello i want to show the collectionView exactly as the above image. I know that it responsible for UICollectionViewFlowLayout, but unable to do it. Help is much appreciated. Here is my code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
     let yourWidth = (collectionView.bounds.width - 4) / 3.0
     let yourHeight = yourWidth
     return CGSize(width: yourWidth, height: yourHeight)
}
```

Comment: So two items and then three?

Comment: Please check [THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997364/uicollectionview-bounds-width-is-always-600). There they mention why the `collectionView.bounds.width` it will always return the same number 600px. As well they give an clear example what you need to do in order to take the correct width. I hope I helped at leas a bit :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your answer is in your question bro some short of conditions**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        switch indexPath.item {
        case 0,1:
            return CGSize(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 16) / 2, height: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 16) / 2)
        default:
            return CGSize(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 32) / 3, height:  (UIScreen.main.bounds.width) / 3)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @JeeVan TiWari sir it is coming fine.

Comment: sir i have upload a image. can you please tell me how to show a collection view like that image.

Comment: It can be done by uicollectionviewlayout follow this link for understanding https://www.iosapptemplates.com/blog/swift-programming/flexible-cell-sizes-collection-view-layout-swift

Answer (score 1):

If this is what you are looking for than it is pretty easy to do with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

[image: End Result]

I am using cells to be 1:1 ratio, so same width and height, you can play around with padding and item spacing and such to get desired effects.

**Your controller has to conform to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol**

In my test app I did the following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ident")

    view.addSubview(collectionView)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let item = indexPath.item
    let width = collectionView.bounds.size.width
    let padding:CGFloat = 5
    if item < 2 {
        let itemWidth:CGFloat = (width - padding) / 2.0
        return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
    } else {
        let itemWidth:CGFloat = (width - 2 * padding) / 3.0
        return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ident", for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = .red
    return cell
}
```

Comment: yes i want exactly same like this. i am checking it sir

Comment: Sir i have upload a image. can you please tell me how to show a collection view like that image.

Comment: For that you have to create a custom UICollectionViewLayout class with all of the methods that have to be overwritten...quite some work :)