# Show images in collectionview in a varying size grid format

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to show images in a collection view in a grid format in varying sizes with a plus sign (i.e. +2,+3 etc.). It'll look like so...

[image]

I came to know that using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` this can be achieved. So I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50099567/how-to-show-a-collectionview-like-facebook-upload-image-using-swift-4) Stack Overflow question and tried adding this line of code. But it didn't work

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        switch indexPath.item {
        case 0,1:
            return CGSize(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 16) / 2, height: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 16) / 2)
        default:
            return CGSize(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 32) / 3, height:  (UIScreen.main.bounds.width) / 3)
        }
    }
```

Also, if the number of images selected is 2 or 3, then those images should be arranged like so..

[image]

How can I make the images appear like that...?

Comment: i think this link might give you an idea as how to achieve it
https://octodev.net/custom-collectionviewlayout/

Comment: @user308123 you should create a custom UICollectionViewLayout for your collection view. Please have a look at my similar project, it will help
https://github.com/Arunjos/Ainterest

Comment: ok @ arunjos007 I'll have a look at it. Thanks a lot..:)