# Not able to show long long collectionviewcell on left and small cells on right

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` that shows 2 cells on top and 3 at the bottom like given in

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50099567/how-to-show-a-collectionview-like-facebook-upload-image-using-swift-4)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
           let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5

    collectionview2.delegate = self
    collectionview2.dataSource = self
    collectionview2.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ident")

    }
  }


  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return 5
    }


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
 switch indexPath.item {
      case 0,1:
        return CGSize(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 16) / 2, height: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 16) / 2)
      default:
        return CGSize(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 32) / 3, height:  (UIScreen.main.bounds.width) / 3)
      }
}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ident", for: indexPath)
      cell.backgroundColor = .red
      return cell

}
```

But I want to show one long cell on left and 2 small cells on right like so..

[image]

So what changes do I need to make in my answer..?

**EDIT 1** This is the latest output...

code in `sizeForItemAt`..

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
 switch indexPath.item {
      case 0,3:
        return CGSize(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 16) / 2, height: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 16) / 2)
      case 1,2,4:
         return CGSize(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 32) / 3, height:  (UIScreen.main.bounds.width) / 3)
      default:
        return CGSize(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 32) / 3, height:  (UIScreen.main.bounds.width) / 3)
      }

}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check this may be helps you :)

[DynamicHeightForCollectionView](https://github.com/sagarshirbhate/DynamicHeightForCollectionView)

[image: Result Image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass `UICollectionViewLayout`  as below

```
class PinterestLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
//1. Pinterest Layout Delegate
weak var delegate: PinterestLayoutDelegate!

//2. Configurable properties
fileprivate var numberOfColumns = 2
fileprivate var cellPadding: CGFloat = 6

//3. Array to keep a cache of attributes.
fileprivate var cache = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

//4. Content height and size
fileprivate var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0

fileprivate var contentWidth: CGFloat {
  guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
    return 0
  }
  let insets = collectionView.contentInset
  return collectionView.bounds.width - (insets.left + insets.right)
}

override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
  return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
}

override func prepare() {
  // 1. Only calculate once
  guard cache.isEmpty == true, let collectionView = collectionView else {
    return
  }
  // 2. Pre-Calculates the X Offset for every column and adds an array to increment the currently max Y Offset for each column
  let columnWidth = contentWidth / CGFloat(numberOfColumns)
  var xOffset = [CGFloat]()
  for column in 0 ..< numberOfColumns {
    xOffset.append(CGFloat(column) * columnWidth)
  }
  var column = 0
  var yOffset = [CGFloat](repeating: 0, count: numberOfColumns)

  // 3. Iterates through the list of items in the first section
  for item in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {

    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)

    // 4. Asks the delegate for the height of the picture and the annotation and calculates the cell frame.
    let photoHeight = delegate.collectionView(collectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    let height = cellPadding * 2 + photoHeight
    let frame = CGRect(x: xOffset[column], y: yOffset[column], width: columnWidth, height: height)
    let insetFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: cellPadding, dy: cellPadding)

    // 5. Creates an UICollectionViewLayoutItem with the frame and add it to the cache
    let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
    attributes.frame = insetFrame
    cache.append(attributes)

    // 6. Updates the collection view content height
    contentHeight = max(contentHeight, frame.maxY)
    yOffset[column] = yOffset[column] + height

    column = column < (numberOfColumns - 1) ? (column + 1) : 0
  }
}

override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

  var visibleLayoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

  // Loop through the cache and look for items in the rect
  for attributes in cache {
    if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
      visibleLayoutAttributes.append(attributes)
    }
  }
  return visibleLayoutAttributes
}

override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
  return cache[indexPath.item]
}
```

}

See this [Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/392-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest)

Comment: but how do i implement it in my answer @Sh_Khan with what I currently have..?

Comment: see this demo https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/uploads/2017/09/Final_Project.zip