# Swift - Facebook style image grid using UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I'm trying to implement Facebook style image layout in Swift. I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50099567/how-to-show-a-collectionview-like-facebook-upload-image-using-swift-4) and followed the approach suggested by one of the answers. As a result, I **almost** achieved what I wanted to.

[image]

As you can see in the image above, however, there's an overflow: the three smaller cells seems to be taking up more than the screen width. However, if I subtract `0.1` to each of the cell's width, the problem seems to have been solved.

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let item = indexPath.item
        let width = collectionView.bounds.size.width
        let padding:CGFloat = 5
        if item < 2 {
            let itemWidth:CGFloat = (width - padding) / 2.0
            return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
        } else {
            let itemWidth:CGFloat = (width - 2 * padding) / 3.0
            // let itemWidth:CGFloat = (width - 2 * padding) / 3.0 - 0.1  // This WORKS!!
            return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
        }
    }
```

[image]

I guess the overflow is caused by the value of `itemWidth` rounding up. But I feel like subtracting a random hard-coded value is not the best practice when dealing with this kind of issue.

Can anyone suggest a better approach for this?

Below is the full code that is reproducible.

```swift
class ContentSizeCollectionView: UICollectionView {
    override var contentSize: CGSize {
        didSet {
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }
    
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        layoutIfNeeded()
        return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: contentSize.height)
    }
}

class GridVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5
        let collectionView = ContentSizeCollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ident")
        return collectionView
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let item = indexPath.item
        let width = collectionView.bounds.size.width
        let padding:CGFloat = 5
        if item < 2 {
            let itemWidth:CGFloat = (width - padding) / 2.0
            return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
        } else {
            let itemWidth:CGFloat = (width - 2 * padding) / 3.0
            return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
        }
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ident", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
        return cell
    }
}
```

### Update

`floor((width - 2 * padding) / 3.0)` did prevent the overflow, but it leaves a small gap at the end.

[image]

Comment: Try printing the collection view's content inset of section inset. It might not be 0

Comment: @aheze `print(collectionView.contentInset)` prints zero edge insets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
let itemWidth:CGFloat = (width - 2 * padding) / 3.0
```

to this:

```
let itemWidth:CGFloat = floor((width - 2 * padding) / 3.0)
```

You may want to do that with a 2 item row as well.

---

**Edit**

The initial problem is that floating-point numbers are approximations.

So, on an iPhone 8, for example, the view width is `375` points. The cell width calculation of:

```
let padding: CGFloat = 5
let itemWidth:CGFloat = (width - 2 * padding) / 3.0
```

`itemWidth` ends up being `121.666... (repeating)`, which UIKit interprets as `121.66666666666667`.

So, `121.66666666666667 * 3.0 + 10` equals (roughly) `375.00000000000011` and... that is greater than `375.0`.

So, the collection view says "can't fit that on one row."

Using `floor()` fixes the problem, except... ***it hits a really weird bug!***

If you change `numberOfItemsInSection` from `5` to `8`, you'll get two rows of 3, and there will be ***no gap*** on the right.

We can get around this by making the *side* cells slightly narrower than the *center* cell like this:

```
// we want all three to be the same heights
//  1/3 of (width - 2 * padding)
let itemHeight: CGFloat = (width - 2 * padding) / 3.0

// left and right cells will be 1/3 of (width - 2 * padding)
//  rounded down to a whole number
let sideW: CGFloat = floor(itemHeight)

// center cell needs to be
//  full-width minus 2 * padding
//  minus
//  side-width * 2
let centerW: CGFloat = (width - 2 * padding) - sideW * 2
        
// is it left (0), center (1) or right (2)
let n = (item - 2) % 3
        
// use the proper width value
let itemWidth: CGFloat = n == 1 ? centerW : sideW

return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
```

Or, what *seems* to be working is making the width *just slightly smaller* than the floating-point 1/3rd. You used `-0.1`, but it also works with:

```
let itemWidth:CGFloat = ((width - 2 * padding) / 3.0) - 0.0000001
```

In any case, that hopefully explains the reason for the "2 cells instead of 3" issue, and two options for avoiding it.

Comment: Please see the updated post. It did not help much unfortunately.

Comment: @shinhong - are you doing 2 on the first row, and 3 on all the other rows?

Comment: @shinhong - see the **Edit** to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer! So to summarize your answer, normally `floor()` should fix this kind of issue (i.e. cells are automatically distributed to fill the row), but in this specific case it causes a strange gap at the end? Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @shinhong - yes... using the sizes in my answer, `floor(121.66666666666667)` equals `121` ... so `121 * 3 + 10 == 373` which **will** fit into `375`. Just a really, really weird bug in the collection view.